# Combining SSR Prefetch with Dynamic Layouts in Next.js and React-Query

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query, next.js14

I'm working on a project using Next.js 14 and React-Query v5, focusing on a user management system with pages at **/users** and **/users/< id >**. I need to access a list of users across these pages, so I decided to fetch this data server-side in **/users/layout.tsx** and stream it to the client. This setup works well for initial data loading. However, I'm looking to enhance the user experience by loading the dashboard layout (including **DashboardHeader** and **DashboardShell**) on the client side while the users' data is still being fetched.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

- **/app/users/layout.tsx**: Uses React-Query's **HydrationBoundary** and **QueryClient** to prefetch users' data server-side.
- **/app/users/page.tsx**: I want to load DashboardHeader and DashboardShell client-side and display them immediately, using React's **Suspense** for the **UserTable** component until the users' data is fully loaded.
- Accessing data in child components like **/app/users/user-table.tsx** and **/app/users/[slug]/page.tsx** is done using useQuery.
  My question is: Is there a way to initiate data prefetching server-side in **layout.tsx**, make it available across all subpages, and simultaneously allow for dynamic client-side loading of the dashboard layout components? I haven't found a solid approach to achieve this without compromising either client-side loading or maintaining a consistent suspense across all subsequent pages. Ideally, I'd like the prefetch to start, dashboard components to load immediately, and Suspense to wait until the data is ready before streaming it to the user.

I would be happy about any help. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
// /app/users/layout.tsx
import React from 'react'
import {HydrationBoundary, QueryClient, dehydrate} from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { getUsers } from './getUsers'

export default async function AccountLayout({children}: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({queryKey: ['users'], queryFn: getUsers, staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5})

  return <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>{children}</HydrationBoundary>
}
```

```
// /app/users/page.tsx
export default async function UsersPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <DashboardHeader heading="Accounts" text="Manage the Accounts" />
      <DashboardShell>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}> // Suspense here
          <UserTable />
        </React.Suspense>
      </DashboardShell>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// /app/users/user-table.tsx
export default function UserTable() {
  const { data } = useSuspenseQuery({
    queryKey: ['users'],
    queryFn: getUsers,
    staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  })
```

Comment: Has somebody an idea?
I don't know if it's possible. But it would be nice if you could prefetch the data in layout.tsx so that the data is then available for all sub pages. But each component could display its own suspense.